# How do western publishers react to drafts that are obviously ripoffs of an existing work?

Tags: publishing, editing, publisher

For example, lets say you were to submit a draft to a publisher that is an obvious ripoff of an existing, popular series (like LOTR). Popular view is that an editor or whoever is in charge of reading drafts rejects it for obvious reasons and it never gets published.

But obviously some obvious ripoffs do get published. How does this happen? Doesnt an editor get involved at some stage of the process and go "hey, wait a minute, this is obviously a ripoff of another book, you can't do this."?

Eragon is probably the most famous example. How did an editor not point out the issues with it? And I just read the wiki article for "The Sword of Shannara" and the introduction scene for that is lifted straight out of LOTR. Again, how did an editor not notice this?

And furthermore, how do these publishers (and their authors) avoid getting sued for plagiarism?

Comment: i recall you used Eragon in a similar question. is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eragon) the Eragon you are referring to? if so what exactly is it a famous example of? i've only seen the movie adaption and i don't recall it ripping off anything else i've read/seen

Comment: also, in regards to your comments about The Sword of Shannara as per the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sword_of_Shannara) which may also help answer part of your question *"Critics have derided the novel for being derivative of J.R.R. Tolkien's The Lord of the Rings. Some have accused Brooks of lifting the entire plot and many of his characters directly from Lord of the Rings; **others have regarded the book more favorably and say that new writers often start by copying the style of established writers.**"*

Comment: Memor, please at least google the topic before you make comments like this. I have seen you argue that copying entire scenes wholesale is not plagiarism, which just smacks of fanboyism. There will always be some people who argue that copying is flattery and quoting them doesn't prove anything.

Considering that you don't believe that wholesale copying of scenes is plagiarism, I don't think we have anything to discuss here as you are not using the commonly accepted definition of plagiarism.

Comment: in [your previous question on this subject but in relation to japanese media works](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/38207/1587) i don't recall arguing *"that copying entire scenes wholesale is not plagiarism"* but ofcause having not seen either anime of *Hundred* or *Infinite Satros* i can not say if the actual animated scenes are identical nor would i have said if either does copy and entire scene frame for frame. what i tried to point out is that IS is about a boy being trained to use weaponry that only girls could use while *Hundred* is about a boy training to help stop an alien invasion

Comment: *Eragon* was self-published because the author was 15 and his parents owned a press. There may not have been an editor involved. Beyond that, popularity may have had its own inertia.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum From what I read, Eragon was only self published before someone from a major publisher happened to pick up the book, thought it was awesome then helped them to publish it. Until they were picked up by a major publisher, Eragon had zero popularity and the author had to resort to giving talks at book stores to try and sell a few dozen copies of his book each time. The impression I got was that it was some executive's pet project (because he really liked the book) and he probably didn't care that it copied scenes wholesale.

Comment: @Question if you are referring to the comparison [here](https://aydee.wordpress.com/2006/12/17/eragon/) as copying scenes wholesale, how is a princess sending 2 droids to a former Jedi she knows of who ended up being captured and traded to the hero's family before one wanders off to continue his mission, a wholesale copy of a princess using magic to randomly send an egg away which suddenly appears in front of the hero as he is hunting? where is the rescue of the princess from the prison located inside the weapon of mass destruction? where is Luke fighting Darth Vader?

Comment: It is pretty clear that this question is rhetorical and is really just an excuse to rant. Therefore I am voting to close it.

Comment: Eragon isn't a famous example. Most people haven't actually heard of it. If I wanted to, I could call Harry Potter a ripoff of other wizarding school books that came before it

Answer (score 1):

Neither of your examples are examples of plagiarism.
Thankfully there is far more leeway in the process.

**Titles Not Protected By Copyright**

For example, did you know that titles are not protected by copyright?
That means that you can actually write a book named Lord of the Rings also.

However, characters do fall under copyright protection so you wouldn't be able to write a book named, Harry Potter & The Chamber of Secrets.

The Chamber of Secrets is fine, however.

**At An Abstract Level, All Fantasy Novels Are the Same**

Also, consider the fact that many fantasy novels are the same.
Thank goodness no one can protect all stories that

> have a short character (Bilbo) who begins a mysterious journey with a
>   wizard and ends up fighting a dragon.

Think about how few fantasy novels there would be.

**Eragon?**

Also, I've read Eragon and I'm not sure what book you think it is ripping off. It's obviously, not obvious.

Sentences, characters (to a certain extent) are protected.
But think about this too, even with characters there has to be some leniency otherwise James Bond would be the one and only spy novel you'd ever get to read.

Many authors are inspired by other novels (positively and negatively) to write their own novels and it really isn't a problem.

**Mona Lisa: Only Portrait of a Woman**

How about art?  What if the Mona Lisa were the only "portrait of an interesting woman" that was allowed to be painted?  That'd be quite terrible too wouldn't it?

Here's the deal: write your novel.  Write your character and story and if it comes out of you, it may look a bit like another author's stuff, but it won't be.  It will just be you.

Comment: Just google "Eragon ripoff" if you want to know which series it rips off of. I mean, its a really famous example and upon it's release (both in book and movie form) many people pointed this out. https://www.google.com.au/search?q=eragon+ripoff&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=CvluWMOADoXs0gSF856QCw

Nobody is referring to an abstract level. Im talking about shameless copying of scenes and writing stories that are pretty much the same with some minor details changed. For example, I could write a copy of LOTR, but change the character names and make the MC a human insstead of a hobbit.

Comment: Also, your answer fails to address the question in any way, the question is how do western publishers react to obvious ripoffs, not what you think constitutes a ripoff. The question is about the publishers reaction to it.

Comment: @Question my google search says it's a rip off of star wars....but i don't see how? as for your second point about Lord of the Rings, if you did that you might expect the same reaction as what Wikipedia states about The Sword of Shannara, some people will call you out for ripping off Lord of the Rings while others will defends you for doing what alot of new writers do

Comment: Memor, please, the first result on google literally explains it. https://aydee.wordpress.com/2006/12/17/eragon/

Comment: @Question i read that and i don't see it, the post author is comparing the opening of a 4th title of a series to the opening the first title of another series. consider that Luke's "appearance" was prophesied way back in the first title and the very same prophecy is what led to the Jedi's downfall as apart of a long running conflict between the Sith and Jedi. the Dragonriders were hunted down by Galbatorix who blamed the dragonrider council for the death of his dragon which caused him to go insane. also note that Jedi use the same invisible force as the Sith while dragonriders used dragons

Comment: from that wordpress site *"Eragon is Luke Skywalker, with a dragon instead of a lightsaber.  It’s cloning, and lazy cloning at that."* that is incorrect. lightsaber != Saphira as Saphira is the source of Eragon's abilities and if he dies so does Saphira. Luke uses The Force and the Lightsaber is just a traditional weapon of Force Users and if Luke dies the Lightsaber will still work with someone else. also be aware the difference in how Luke and Eragon treat the lightsaber and Saphira. Eragon would protect and care for Saphira, Luke didn't go back to get his lightsaber and just made a new one

Comment: and in fact Saphira chides him at the very last in 'Inheritance' as to why he put his life in danger for her. IIRC this also happens in 'Eragon' as well.